# Defining interface of abstract class in shared library

Tags: c++, c++14, dlopen, dlsym

Say I have a abstract base class defined like so:

**interface.hpp**

```
#ifndef INTERFACE_HPP
#define INTERFACE_HPP 1

class interface{
    public:
        virtual void func() = 0;
};

#endif // INTERFACE_HPP
```

Then I compile a translation unit `test.cpp` into a shared object `test.so`:

**test.cpp**

```
#include "interface.hpp"
#include <iostream>

class test_interface: public interface{
    public:
        void func(){std::cout << "test_interface::func() called\n";}
};

extern "C"
interface &get_interface(){
    static test_interface test;
    return test;
}
```

If I open that shared object in an executable and try to call `get_interface` like this:

```
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include "interface.hpp"

int main(){
    void *handle = dlopen("test.so", RTLD_LAZY);
    void *func = dlsym(handle, "get_interface");

    interface &i = reinterpret_cast<interface &(*)()>(func)();
    i.func(); // print "test_interface::func() called"

    dlclose(handle);
}
```

(just pretend I did error checking)

**Is the behaviour well defined? Or am I stepping on my own toes by assuming this will always work?**

*Keep in mind I will only ever be using clang and gcc*

Comment: If you're using the same compiler then I see no reason this could go wrong. I've just ported your sample to msvc (2015rc) and it works there, too.

Comment: You should be fine as long as you maintain binary compatibility.  See these...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1774911/how-to-design-a-c-api-for-binary-compatible-extensibility

https://techbase.kde.org/Policies/Binary_Compatibility_Issues_With_C++

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3217513/are-llvm-gcc-and-clang-binary-compatible-with-gcc-particularly-mingw-gcc-on-w

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One gotcha is that you want `protected: ~interface()` to discourage clients from deleting `interface`.

A second, practical issue is that if you modify `interface`, remember to add the methods at the **end** of the class only, and do not add new virtual overrides (functions with the same name).  (In practice, I have seen overrides be clustered together, even if they are not clustered in the header file).

If you want more than just a single interface (say, your interface inherits from 2 other interfaces), use `virtual` inheritance.  Adding new `virtual` parents after the fact has in my experience proved problematic as well.

None of this is defined by the C++ standard, which is agnostic on the subject of binary interfaces and run time loading of code.  However, the above is my experience using a similar technique (admittedly, with pointers instead of references, and using MSVC instead of gcc/clang).

You do have to keep track of what the ABI is on the compilers you use.  If you pass `std` structures over such an interface, be aware that they sometimes change layout (`std::string` in gcc going from reference counted to not, for example, or `std::list` getting O(1) `size`), and they are not all that likely to be layout-compatible between compilers (well, standard libraries, which different compilers tend to use different ones by default).